# ammap balloon click event

Tags: javascript, ammap

Is there anyway of tracking the click on a balloon, on a AmMap?

**This one seems to track click anywhere on the map.**

```
map.addListener("click", handleMapClick);
```

**Whilst this has no effect whatsoever.**

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", handleMapObjectClick);
```

-

```
function handleMapClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}

function handleMapObjectClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfnw9mxx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, try changing:

```
    dataProvider.images.push({
        type: "circle",
        width: size,
        height: size,
        // color: dataItem.color,
        longitude: heatmapData[i].lon,
        latitude: heatmapData[i].lat,
        title: heatmapData[i].country,
        value: heatmapData[i].count
    });
```

to:

```
    dataProvider.images.push({
        type: "circle",
        width: size,
        height: size,
        // color: dataItem.color,
        longitude: heatmapData[i].lon,
        latitude: heatmapData[i].lat,
        title: heatmapData[i].country,
        value: heatmapData[i].count,
        selectable: true
    });
```

(see, last line, add selectable).

This appears to be an undocumented requirement. It's given away by the amcharts demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/6WVvS/ linked to/"documented" at: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/interacting-between-javascript-charts-and-javascript-maps/

Comment: (hugefaceslap), but that was definitely hard to figure out.